# Spark Kryo register for array class

Tags: java, apache-spark, kryo

I am trying to register a class with array (Spark Java with Kryo activated), log shows a clear message:

```
Class is not registered: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$SerializableBlockLocation[]
```

I have written several combinations, but these do not work:

```
        kryo.register(Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$SerializableBlockLocation[]")); // ERROR
        kryo.register(Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$SerializableBlockLocation[].class")); // ERROR
        kryo.register(Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$SerializableBlockLocation$Array")); // ERROR
        kryo.register(Class.forName("[org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$SerializableBlockLocation")); // ERROR
        kryo.register(Class.forName("[Lorg.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$SerializableBlockLocation")); // ERROR
        kryo.register(Class.forName("Array[org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$SerializableBlockLocation]")); // ERROR
        kryo.register(Class.forName("[[org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$SerializableBlockLocation"));  // ERROR
```

I also tried to write a registration class without `Class.forName` but Java cannot resolve the symbol `InMemoryFileIndex$SerializableBlockLocation`:

```
kryo.register(org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$SerializableBlockLocation[].class);
```

All other classes work in my KryoRegister.class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a similar question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/kryo-users/9yobtSM9mmg/_yT4GTku3pMJ), try:

```
kryo.register(Array.newInstance(Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$SerializableBlockLocation"), 0)
                        .getClass());
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out you can also try:

```
spark.kryo.classesToRegister [Lorg.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SerializableBlockLocation;
```

to register `"org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SerializableBlockLocation[]"`